# Firefox Appcache console logging

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, gruntjs, html5-appcache

I have appcache implemented in a Web app I'm working on (generated by a grunt task) and it works fine.

The only thing I'm wondering about is displaying the resources being appcached.  For example in Chrome Developer console it shows the Appcache Update event (and displays when its done).

However, in Firefox 31.0 I don't know if there is a way to duplicate Chrome's Developer appcache console log.

Is there some addon that can duplicate this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You can try Firebug as mention this page [Firebug AppCache Test Case](https://getfirebug.com/tests/1.9/dom/appCache/appCache.html)